# Excel VBA cell returns "0" despite having value

Tags: vba, excel, google-api, excel-udf

I'm working on a task where I need to get an access token for the Google Analytics API from Excel using Google's oAuth 2.0 integration.

The initial request works by passing in the client id, secret key and the authentication token which are stored in cells within my worksheet.

The UDF I'm using looks like so:

```
Public Function GetGAAuthenticationToken _
                    (ByVal ClientId As String,  _
                    ByVal ClientSecret As String,  _
                    ByVal code As String,  _
                    accessToken As String,  _
                    RefreshToken As String,  _
                    accessTokenExpires As Date)

  'Has token expire? If not, don't renew the access token.
  Dim Token(2, 0)
  Dim Refresh As Boolean: Refresh = True

  If Now < accessTokenExpires Then
    Token(0, 0) = accessToken
    Token(1, 0) = RefreshToken
    Token(2, 0) = accessTokenExpires
    Refresh = False
  End If

  Dim objhttp As Object
  Dim ResponseText As String

  If Refresh Then
      If RefreshToken = "" Or RefreshToken = "0" Then
        'Initial authorization code=GetGAAuthenticationToken(B1, B2, B4, B6, B7, B8)
        Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
        objhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
        objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        objhttp.setTimeouts 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000
        objhttp.send ("code=" & code & "&client_id=" & ClientId & "&client_secret=" _
          & ClientSecret _
          & "&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2%2E0%3Aoob&grant_type=authorization_code")

        ResponseText = objhttp.ResponseText
      Else
        'Refresh Token
        Set objhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
        URL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"
        objhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
        objhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        objhttp.setTimeouts 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000
        objhttp.send  _
          ("client_id=" & ClientId  _
           & "&client_secret=" & ClientSecret & "&refresh_token=" _
           & RefreshToken & "&grant_type=refresh_token")

        ResponseText = objhttp.ResponseText
      End If

      Dim XMLResponse:    Set XMLResponse = JSONtoXML(ResponseText)
      Dim XMLResult:    Set XMLResult = XMLResponse.SelectSingleNode("//XML")

      If Not IsNull(XMLResult.GetAttribute("access_token")) Then
        Token(0, 0) = XMLResult.GetAttribute("access_token")
      End If
      If Not IsNull(XMLResult.GetAttribute("refresh_token")) Then
        Token(1, 0) = XMLResult.GetAttribute("refresh_token")
      Else
        Token(2, 0) = RefreshToken
      End If
      If Not IsNull(XMLResult.GetAttribute("expires_in")) Then
        If IsNumeric(XMLResult.GetAttribute("expires_in")) Then
           Token(2, 0) = DateAdd("s", CInt(XMLResult.GetAttribute("expires_in")), Now)
        Else
            Token(2, 0) = DateAdd("s", 3600, Now)
        End If
      Else
        Token(2, 0) = DateAdd("s", 3600, Now)
      End If
  End If

  GetGAAuthenticationToken = Token

End Function
```

In my worksheet I've got an array of cells that call the function:

```
=GetGAAuthenticationToken(B1, B2, B4, B5, B6, B7)
```

As I said above, the initial request works fine and outputs the access token, refresh token and access token expiry date into cells B5, B6 and B7.

However, when I run the request again, where I would expect the values from B5, B6 and B7 to be passed through to my UDF, they come through as "0". It seems like they're being reset between me triggering the update and the UDF executing. Is it possible to get these value?

I've come across this page http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/writing-efficient-vba-udfs-part-8-getting-the-previously-calculated-value-from-the-calling-cells/ which seems to be similar to what I'm trying to do, however this appears to be for a single field rather than an array?

I'm not at all experienced in Excel and VBA so any assistance is welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your function to take `Range` arguments, rather than string/date arguments. UDF's with references to "B1" pass a `Range` object.

```
Public Function GetGAAuthenticationToken(ByVal p_ClientId As Range, ByVal p_ClientSecret As Range, ByVal p_code As Range, p_accessToken As Range, _
p_RefreshToken As Range, p_accessTokenExpires As Range)
```

Then declare your variables and set them to the value of the range objects:

```
Dim ClientId As String
Dim ClientSecret As String
Dim code As String
Dim accessToken As String
Dim RefreshToken As String
Dim accessTokenExpires As Date

ClientId = p_ClientId.value
ClientSecret = p_ClientSecret.value
code = p_code.value
accessToken = p_accessToken.value
RefreshToken = p_RefreshToken.value
accessTokenExpires = p_accessTokenExpires.value
```

Note I changed the naming of your arguments so you don't have to modify your variable names. You can of course change this if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've tried what you've suggested, unfortunately I'm still getting back "0" from the `AccessToken`, `RefreshToken` and `AccessTokenExpires` cells. The other cells return their values fine using your code...

Answer (score 0):

Haven't really examined your code, but there might be a data type issue in there somewhere.  Try changing the incoming values from "As String", to "As Range" and look at the values (e.g. accessToken.Value) inside the function with the debugger.

In my experience, it's never safe to type things coming into a UDF as anything other than Range, because Excel can store all kinds of datatypes in a cell.  Better to grab the values from the range references inside the function.  I learned this the hard way....

Best of luck!